How to specify spacing between two bands in Jasper Reports?
I have this part of jasper reports markup:
<band height="15">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="220" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>First band</text>
            </staticText>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="235" y="0" width="320" height="15">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><Some data that big enough to fit more than one row></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="15">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="220" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>Second band</text>
            </staticText>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="235" y="0" width="320" height="15">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><Second band data></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>

Problem is that when value of textField in first band is too long (for example 130 symbols), I see that spacing between last row of textField in first band and first row of textField in second band is smaller than usual spacing
Here the example:
Image example
How can I make it usual-sized?
I tried to set PositionType to Float and splitType to Prevent, so it was like this:
<band height="15" splitType="Prevent">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="220" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>First band</text>
            </staticText>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="235" y="0" width="320" height="15">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="positionType" value="Float"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><Some data that big enough to fit more than one row></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <!-- The same thing I did to second band -->

But nothing changed((
